# Solving $3^x=-1/3$, or more generally $a^x=b$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I was playing around with some equations and I got here: $$3^x = -\frac{1}{3}$$ $$ x = \text{?} $$ How can I find $x$?

I tried to use $\sqrt \frac{-1}{3}$, but I think a square root of a negative number is impossible.

In that case, how can I do: $$a^x = b$$ $$x = \text{?} $$

Please someone help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3582783/401264) is correct that there is no answer when it comes to your specific question.

In the general case, $a^x=b$, you should go and read up on [logarithms](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra2/x2ec2f6f830c9fb89:logs/x2ec2f6f830c9fb89:log-intro/a/intro-to-logarithms), but in general, the answer would be $$x=\log_a(b)$$

Answer (score 2):

In the complex, taking the logarithm, your equation is

$$x\ln(3)=\ln\left(-\frac13\right)=\ln\left(\frac13\right)+i(2k+1)\pi$$ where you select a "branch" by choosing $k$.

Hence

$$x=-1+i\frac{(2k+1)\pi}{\ln(3)}.$$

Comment: OP probably doesn't even know what the logarithm itself is.

Comment: @lonestudent: I agree with you. Anyway, he could spend a hard time *without* logarithms at all.

Answer (score 1):

If $x$ is real number you cannot have $3^{x} =-\frac  1 3 $ because $3^{x} >0$.

Answer (score 0):

If $x$ is real number then $a^x>0$.
So $3^x=-1/3$ does not have a real solution.
If $3^{x}=1/3 \implies 3^x=3^{-1} \implies x=-1.$
If a^x=b \implies $x=\log_a b$ where both $a,b>0$

Answer (score 0):

To solve an equation the form of which is $ ax = b$ with $b\gt0$, it is generally adviced to " take the logarithm of both sides"  ( in general base 10 log or natural log, i.e. base $e$).

This is surely the most efficient procedure, though a bit mechanical.

Personnaly, I really like using this property :

***any positive number $n$ can be written as a power with any positive base $b$***, that is, in the aaforementionned conditions,

***$n$ is always equal to $b^{\log_b(n)}$***.

The reason is that : when I raise base $b$ to "the power to which I have to raise $b$ in order to get $n$", the " result" must be $n$ itself.

Applying this to your question, with a positive RHS , it is possible to express the fraction $\frac 13$ as a power of $3$:

$3^x = \frac 13$

$\rightarrow$ $3^x = 3^{\log_3(\frac 13)}$   ( By the property I mentionned above).

$\rightarrow$ $x = \log_3{(\frac 13})$ ( By : " equal powers with same base have equal exponents") .

$\rightarrow$ $ x = \log_3(1) - \log_3(3)$ ( by the " log of a quotient" rule)

$\rightarrow$ $ x = 0 - 1 = -1 $

Note : applying this method may lead to non standard base logarithms, but one can always convert them using the " change of base formula".

Answer (score 0):

Your question has an easy answer and a difficult one.

For all 'normal' reals like $3^x=7$ you take the $\log_3$ of both sides and choose your way of working out $\log_3(7)$

The difficult solution requires a step outside conventional thought on the nature of numbers since it introduces complex numbers. Check out the links for a beautiful intro to the subject.

https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLiaHhY2iBX9g6KIvZ_703G3KJXapKkNaF

https://youtu.be/mvmuCPvRoWQ

But evaluating your example:

$3^x=-1 \cdot 3^{-1}$

$x=\log_3(-1 \cdot 3^{-1})$

$=-1+\log_3{(-1)}$

$\log_3{(-1)}=\frac{\ln(-1)}{\ln(3)}$

$e^{iπ}=-1$

$\ln(-1)=i\pi + 2n\pi \quad n \in \mathbb{N}$

If you research on this it will make sense to you and hopefully you will find beauty in it.

What's a logarithm? If this is unclear, you have a lot to learn, which is in a way a good thing.

https://youtu.be/sULa9Lc4pck